# Извлечение текстового узла у предпоследнего li из списка ul

Tags: javascript, dom

С учётом возможного незначительного изменения html-разметки в будущем, **как правильно написать код и извлечь из предпоследнего li название категории к которой принадлежит товар, в не зависимости от вложенности товара**?
В данном примере html-разметка хлебных крошек.

```js
var crumbs = document.getElementById('crumbs');
crumbs = crumbs.lastElementChild;
crumbs = crumbs.previousElementSibling;
var productCat = crumbs.getElementsByClassName('text-el');
productCat = productCat[0].innerText;
console.log(productCat);
```

```html
<p>tetet</p><ul class="items items-crumbs" id="crumbs">
  <li class="btn-crumb">
    <a href="https://site-name.ru/" typeof="v:Breadcrumb">
                    <span class="text-el">Главная</span>
                    <span class="divider">/</span>
                </a>
  </li>
  <li class="btn-crumb">
    <a href="https://site-name.ru/shop/category/konditsionirovanie" typeof="v:Breadcrumb">
                            <span class="text-el">Кондиционирование</span>
                            <span class="divider">/</span>
                        </a>
  </li>
  <li class="btn-crumb">
    <a href="https://site-name.ru/shop/category/konditsionirovanie/nastennye-split-sistemy" typeof="v:Breadcrumb">
                            <span class="text-el">Настенные сплит системы</span>
                            <span class="divider">/</span>
                        </a>
  </li>
  <li class="btn-crumb">
    <button typeof="v:Breadcrumb" disabled="disabled">
                            <span class="text-el">Сплит система Mitsubishi Electric MSZ-HJ25VA-ER1/MUZ-HJ25VA-ER1</span>
                        </button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Извлечение текстового узла у предпоследнего li из списка ul

При условии, что у всех кроме последнего ваших `li`, есть якоря.

Можно вот так:

```js
// Выборка всех li с якорем из родительского ul
var btns = document.querySelectorAll('#crumbs > .btn-crumb > a > .text-el')
// Последний li из выборки
console.log(btns[btns.length -1].innerText);
```

```html
<p>tetet</p>
<ul class="items items-crumbs" id="crumbs">
  <li class="btn-crumb">
    <a href="https://site-name.ru/" typeof="v:Breadcrumb">
      <span class="text-el">Главная</span>
      <span class="divider">/</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="btn-crumb">
    <a href="https://site-name.ru/shop/category/konditsionirovanie" typeof="v:Breadcrumb">
      <span class="text-el">Кондиционирование</span>
      <span class="divider">/</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="btn-crumb">
    <a href="https://site-name.ru/shop/category/konditsionirovanie/nastennye-split-sistemy" typeof="v:Breadcrumb">
      <span class="text-el">Настенные сплит системы</span>
      <span class="divider">/</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="btn-crumb">
    <button typeof="v:Breadcrumb" disabled="disabled">
                            <span class="text-el">Сплит система Mitsubishi Electric MSZ-HJ25VA-ER1/MUZ-HJ25VA-ER1</span>
                        </button>
  </li>
</ul>
```